# Vehicle shipping between Europe and the Caribbean

Tags: automobiles, caribbean, shipping, bosnia

I am looking for general advice on shipping and maintaing a vehicle between Eastern Europe (Bosnia) and the Caribbean (Dominica) as I am getting closer to my plan to be able to live in both places 6 months at a time in each.  E.g. ship operators, paperwork, where is it better to have the vehicle registered etc.

Originally I thought of having a truck in each location but then one would have to sit idle while I am in the other location.  Plus, the chances are I would have lots of cargo (sporting as well as construction equipment) upon every migration so stuffing it all in a truck and then putting it in a ferry could make sense.  Plus, of course, the cost of the extra vehicle (I am thinking of a Toyota HiLux).

So for starters, I am looking for advice where to start looking for information and what I should be considering.  Also, I believe the vehicle taxes would be cheaper in Bosnia, could I drive it as a foreign vehicle on the island without paying the local taxes?  I am looking for general advice regarding this matter, any info is welcome.

Comment: Probably better for the [Expats Proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38732/expatriates)

Comment: @amphibient Judging by your question you either intend to earn money in Dominica or avoid taxation in your home country or am I missing something?

Comment: neither, i am just looking for ways to engineer a comfortable lifestyle between two locations

Comment: In my experience, it is more trouble than it is worth. Sell the vehicle in your home country and buy something nice when you get where you are going.

Comment: +1 to the above. The expense is one thing, the hassles are another. International shipping does not run with the temporal precision of Swiss trains, and then there is customs. Dominica is small, beautiful, and temperate - buy a motor scooter or two there, and hire a truck locally when you need to haul things. Why be in the Caribbean and stuck inside a vehicle when you could have the wind in your hair?